# SEO and Session Parameters

Tags: seo, session-variables

If we develop a site with SEO compatible, is it possible to use Session Variables?
If not what is the alternative?
Thanks many.
Best regards.

Comment: What do you mean by session variables?

Comment: What does SEO has to do with Sessionvariables?

Answer (score 2):

A search engine indexes pages on your site based on their URLs. If your URLs are not dependent on the unique Session ID assigned to every request, then a spider should not have a problem indexing your site.

That said, the content of your pages also matters. If the page content relies heavily on Session variables (or Viewstate params), you might have a problem getting that page indexed. The best way is to have unique and static URLs for each section of your site.

Comment: But one more question: does Search Engine create a session while page indexing?

Comment: Sessions are created by a Server when serving requests. Search engine bots operate just like normal users in that respect.

Comment: That's all... Best regards, Cerebrus.

Comment: In case you may not be aware of this (since you're new here), you should accept the most suitable answer after your issue has been suitably addressed. Of course, you might want to wait for further answers. ;-)

Answer (score 1):

You should use cookies, because they are machine dependent. Session identifiers in the URL are very unsave (session-stealing), because you lose your session if you send the url to somebody.

Answer (score 1):

From [Googles Webmaster Guide](http://www.google.com/support/webmasters/bin/answer.py?answer=35769#2):

> "Allow search bots to crawl your sites without session IDs or arguments that track their path through the site. These techniques are useful for tracking individual user behavior, but the access pattern of bots is entirely different. Using these techniques may result in incomplete indexing of your site, as bots may not be able to eliminate URLs that look different but actually point to the same page."

So I don't think tht it is a good idea to require content that you want indexed to require a session.  It depends on what your requirements are as to possible alternatives/workarounds.

Answer (score 0):

I agree with Cerebrus. Just make sure that

- You have unique and static URLs. If you don't have unique urls you will loose the links to that page.
- You have the same title for all states of a page
- You target the same keywords for all states of a page

Answer (score 0):

Session variables can be passed in a HTTP request as a cookie, a POST variable, or in the URL.

Search engines do not support cookies or POST variables, and it they try to avoid pages with session variables in the URL.

You can use cookie or POST based session tracking for your users, but be aware that requests from search engines will always appear as the start of a new session.

Answer (score 0):

URL is independent on the unique Session ID assigned to every request, then the web spider should not have a problem indexing your site on google.